# How to create single page html for RESTful service

Tags: java, html, ajax, rest, single-page-application

I have a restful service as follow, which provides simple CRUD operations, as follow.

Here the url path is mapped to the class first (/UerService) and then to the individual methods.

```
@Path("/UserService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@GET
@Path("/getuser/{id}")
public User getUser(int id){
   //DB select code goes here
}

@PUT
@Path("/updateuser")
public void updateUser(User user){
   //DB update code goes here

  }

@POST
@Path("/insertuser")
public void insertUser(User user){
       //DB insert code goes here
     }
}
```

So, the url address of the methods are like /UserService/getuser/123, /UserService/updateuser etc

Now, I need to create an html (Single page) which will have calls to all the methods.

Where I am struggling is that, how to build the url for the html form action, as the page is going to have a single form and also I can retrieve the form parameters using @formParam.

Should the form action be the class level path like: action="/UserService" and then individual buttons (for get, insert, update etc) should have some ajax calls with individual method's path url pattern?

I am not quite familiar with the Single page html design, so any recommendation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than submitting your data as a form, you can wire up the page so that each button has it's own event handler - this can then make the relevant ajax call depending on which element was selected.

A quick search on jquery ajax should give you some good examples of sending ajax requests using specific data rather than an html form.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for clarifying.